# Why SSIS rows showing Unable to fetch column name are processed while executing them explicity?

Tags: postgresql, ssis, ssis-2012

Task :-
I've SSIS package that load data From SQLServer to PostgreSQL Database.

Mechanism :-
For each loop only 100 records are picked and processed to destination till all records are process.

OnLoad events:-
While loading data to PostgreSQL there are triggers on table that do their activity to sync data to SalesForce, which cannot be disable currently while migration.

Issue:-
While loading data some records are loading in to Error table used in DFT ,for which **Error Column Name** is coming with value "**Unable to fetch column name**".

[image]

Now here's the thing weird, if i reprocess same error rows they are processed successfully to destination.

[image]
Really appreciate if someone came under same scenario and can share their experience to debug this further.

Comment: You would need to provide enough information to reproduce the error for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: @TabAlleman ,please suggest what other information is required to make this query more readable.

Comment: At a minimum, we would need to see the workings of the dataflow task, and the source data that is causing the error.